# Problema para instalar visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual, studio, visual-studio-2022

Me podrían ayudar con este problema, les contaré un poco, resulta que tenía elprograma y sufrí de un problema con el .net framework porlo que me recomendaron desinstalar el programa, ahora ue lo necesito instalar de nuevo no puedo por los problemas que me surgen a continuación:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Tal vez si eliminas los archivos temporales y tratas de instalar de nuevo. _C:\Users\tunombredeusuario\AppData\Local\Temp_